# Are Windows viruses compatible with Mac OS ones?

Tags: batch-file, virus

I'm just starting with coding and I just created a Windows virus (using bat file) but I wanted to send it to a friend with Mac to test it... is it possible? Or do I need to create a specific Mac virus in order to make it work?

Comment: You may have gotten an answer if you just were curious but so since you said you made one and wanted to test it out on your friend... I think the chances are a bit lower. This isn't really the right site for your question as it is anyway.

Comment: I just don't want to risk it and destroy his computer. What would be a better site to ask this question anyway?

Comment: How were you planning to send it? By email? Batch files get blocked for security reasons.

Comment: @MariaRomanza - There does not exist a Stack Exchange community, where this type of question, would be within scope.  We are not going to help you write a virus, even if it's a learning excerise, it simply not something we can help you with.

Comment: oh I'm not asking you to help me write a virus... I'm just asking if Windows viruses work with Mac. Chill..

Comment: "Chill" .. are you aged about 13?

Answer (score 5):

Neither a .bat file nor an .exe will even run on a Mac, so no, your [hopefully innocuous] test will do nothing at all.

Going forward - viruses, even beginner ones, should never be tested on regular machines with data or even just time to lose. Use VMs or disposable hardware installs, not connected to any network.

Don't **ever** send them to unsuspecting people.

Even if you think it's a joke, they may not see the funny side of it at all. At worst, you could destroy data they don't have backed up, which could cost them time & effort, or even serious financial or emotional loss.
If it is traceable back to you, you could be sued or even arrested.

I just checked [UK law](https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/computer-misuse) - 10 years' imprisonment...

> **Section 3 CMA - Unauthorised Acts with intent to impair, or with recklessness as to impairing the operation of a computer**
>   The
>   maximum sentence on indictment is 10 years' imprisonment.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this! Although I think those laws are set by country right?

Comment: Correct - though unless you live in *"outer Timbuktu"*, then your country will probably have something very similar.